# Downside to using pointers to allow classes to act as a data templates for creating instances of another class

Tags: c++, pointers, optimization

I have been stumbling over this issue for a while now where I end up wanting to separate the data from the class I want to make and turn it into a pointer in the class.

Say for example I wanted to create an Item Class for an RPG game I keep trying to go:

```
class ItemTemplate
{
     public:
        enum TYPE { //Item types here. };
        //ctor's and methods here.
     private:
        std::string m_name;
        int m_buyprice;
        int m_sellprice;
        TYPE m_type;
        int m_maxUses;
}
```

Basically the ItemTemplate is used to define any data that is constant for all instances of any Item object of that type like so:

```
const ItemTemplate cPotionTemplate( "Potion" , HEALING , 300 , 50 , 3 );
```

says all potions are called "Potion", are of the HEALING item types, cost 300G and sell for 50g and have 3 uses to start. None of that data is ever going to change. It would probably be more accurate for it to be HealingItemTemplate and to also say how much it recovers but that's getting off the point.

After that I want to create another class

```
class Item
{
     public:
        //ctors and methods here.
     private:
        ItemTemplate* m_Data;
        int m_usesLeft;
}
```

Basically this just accesses the data in the ItemTemplate and tracks the number of uses the item still has.

What I am trying for is to cut down on the number of variables existing in memory when the program is running.

I know I could bundle all of this data into a single class but that would mean that every item would store a copy of data that doesn't or shouldn't change.

Taking `sizeof(int)` to be 4, `sizeof(type)` to be 4, `sizeof(string)` to be 4 and `sizeof( a pointer )` to be 4.

The way I keep trying to implement it uses 8 bytes for each instance of an item but doing the bundled way would use `24 + ( m_name.capacity() or m_name.size() * sizeof(char) )` I know the latter doesn't accurately account for reserved space, but I'm not sure of the former.

Regardless, bundling all the data together in one class would use a minimum of 3x the number of bytes separating the data does. What I am struggling to understand is the downside of such an approach. My current thoughts are that it would be an increase in function calls and copies of data being made. I'm thinking that making the Item class a friend of the ItemTemplate class would be able to eliminate what I would consider a large portion of that increase in calls, those to the accessors.

Basically I'm just really struggling to fully understand the downside of the trade-off I keep wanting to make.

So what are the possible drawbacks to using such an implementation?

What methods exist to help determine when such an implementation is still worth using? If it matters for this I am using Code::Blocks 13.12 IDE but am woefully un-knowledgeable when it comes to using debuggers.

Is there another way to achieve this behavior that I'm missing?
I had considered templates but that seemed too rigid in terms of storing them as each derivation of the `ItemTemplate` class would create a new type `Item<Derived Class>` and no `Item<type>` would be able to be stored together unless they were from the same derivation. Which could work for some systems but isn't the desired implementation as it would make adding new Itemtypes much more of a chore.

Comment: My suggestion would be to worry about this when it becomes a problem. You might find that neither solution makes much of a difference and there isn't much point in stressing over finding a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

An interface class in C++ would solve your concerns regarding the templates:

```
class ItemInterface
{
     public:
        enum TYPE { potion, scroll };
        //ctor's and methods here.
     public:
        virtual std::string getName();
        virtual int get_buyprice();
        virtual int get_sellprice();
        virtual TYPE get_type();
        virtual int get_maxUses();
};


template<ItemInterface::TYPE T>
class item : ItemInterface {
       private:
        //Note, not all static members need to be constant
        static const std::string m_name;
        static const int m_buyprice;
        static const int m_sellprice;
        static const TYPE m_type;
        static const int m_maxUses;

        int m_usesLeft;

       public:
        item();
        /*your getters implementation here*/
        std::string getName(){return m_name;}
        //etc...
};

//Your specialisations here.
//This looks ugly because it's private and const.
//Public static initialization would look better.

template<> const std::string item<ItemInterface::potion>::m_name = "potion";    
//...
template<> const std::string item<ItemInterface::scroll>::m_name = "scroll";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have some questions about your code.

Comment: First is the item class declaration correct. Given your code what I understand is that <typename ItemTemplate::enum> is meant to limit the whatever is between the <> to the values in the enum. I am unclear if you scrapped my code snippets all together or not. It seems as though you meant <typename ItemInterface::TYPE> but one of the reasons I rejected templates was because I didn't know how to limit the types they can be so I'm not sure. Also would item<potion>::m_name = "blue potion"; work or would it need to be <bpotion> or some other unique typename?

Comment: Fixed the `<typename ItemInterface::TYPE>` typo. Correct, if you have two potions, you'd need two enum entries, one for red, one for blue. I don't understand what you mean by "limit the types".

Comment: Basically just stop things like item<int> which makes no sense.
Also is there somewhere I can read about how you have defined the second class. I am still seeing ItemTemplate and I'm not sure if it is meant to be that or ItemInterface. This may be because I don't fully understand what you are doing there.

Comment: Templates are static. They're resolved at compile time... the only way you'd have item<1> is that somebody intentionally used it. There only way to prevent that is having compile time asserts on the template argument, but I don't see the point.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a class called item or one called ItemTemplate. Given you say it will fix the storage concerns I had I'm leaning that it's so I can do something like vector<ItemTemplate>.push_back( item<potion>() );

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Sorry to be difficult.

Comment: Had some sintax errors, fixed them. Yo won't be able to store these objects on a vector, as they're of different classes, but you can store pointers to the interface like this: `vector<ItemInterface*>.push_back(new item<potion>())`

Answer (score 0):

You have identified two designs from the design patterns book.

- Prototype pattern
- Flyweight pattern

### Prototype pattern

[wikipedia prototype pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern)

This assumes the construction of things can be achieved by defining available attributes and constructing a prototype.  It simplifies the amount of subclassing needed, as the difference is only the parameters to the object.

### Flyweight pattern

[wikipedia : flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

This pattern identifies that the state of many instanced objects may be split between "all these are the same" and these are the movable/usable attributes.

You are right to identify that these patterns have both advantages, and disadvantages, but whether they are appropriate, is based on your usage, not easy for people outside of your project to answer.